# dict in django request.session resets to previous value

Tags: django, session, request

According to the task I have to make Django 1.6 chat with Long polling technology (without the use of redis, websokets and so on). For the authorized user I store in the request.session dict with last message ID in each thread (dialogue):

```
request.session['admin_lastid'] = {'dialogue1': 112, 'dialogue2': 34}
```

I have two views with long polling. One `def get_new(request)` scans the ongoing dialogue and updates the dict when a new message:

```
request.session['admin_lastid']['dialogue1'] = current_thread.lastid
request.session.save()
request.session.modified = True
```

Another view `def scan_threads(request)` scans all the dialogue for new messages and this view reads the values from the `request.session['admin_lastid']`.

But I see the strange behavior of the session. When the view get_new is recorded in the `request.session['admin_lastid']` a new value, the next view scan_threads considered the updated value. But when the view get_new start up again, he saw the old value. Why? Can not understand...